# github pages deploying redirects to the repository

Tags: git, github, deployment

i am trying to deploy a dummy website following the guide shown on github pages website here: https://pages.github.com/

but it sends me to my repository. whats going on ?

i am trying to deploy a react website and I followed this guide: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/ under "github pages" section and this also redirects to the github repository page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to consult the right URL, depending on your [GitHub pages repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#about-github-pages)

> There are three types of GitHub Pages sites: project, user, and organization.
>
> - Project sites are connected to a specific project hosted on GitHub, such as a JavaScript library or a recipe collection.
> - User and organization sites are connected to a specific GitHub account.

And:

> - To publish a user site, you must create a repository owned by your user account that's named `<user>.github.io`.
> - To publish an organization site, you must create a repository owned by an organization that's named `<organization>.github.io`. Unless you're using a custom domain, user and organization sites are available at `http(s)://<username>.github.io` or `http(s)://<organization>.github.io`.
>
> The source files for a project site are stored in the same repository as their project. Unless you're using a custom domain, project sites are available at **`http(s)://<user>.github.io/<repository>`** or **`http(s)://<organization>.github.io/<repository>`**.

Comment: hi @VonC, i got to that working, thanks. But I am facing yet another issue. I cannot use pushState api nor any library that uses browserHistory under the hood. I am using react whose SPA  and didnt want to use hash. Do you know how can I make it work with pathname instad of hashes?

Comment: @nishi Not sure. That would be better addressed in a separate question, illustrating the new issue. But first, how did you get it working?

Comment: Yeah. I thought you would say that. It doest make sense after all. Exactly like you said. I searched on that link and found exactly how I want to setup. The problem of pages.github.com is because they ask you to clone with this sample url https://github.com/username/username.github.io but when you create a repository on github its (...)/username:username.github.io. The react tutorial its pretty much just follow along.

Comment: @nishi OK. `github.com/username/username.github.io` would be for a User GitHub Pages sites. Considering the React App uses the `homepage` field of `package.json` to determine the root URL in the built HTML file, I suppose your homepage wasn't matching the type of GitHub Pages repository you had created before.

Comment: Probably. Well, when I was first creating my username.github.io repository when he asked to clone, instead of cloning github.com/username/username.github.io i did clone github.com/username:username.github.io and it worked. now the only issue is because I will have to stick with hash routing pagination instead of pathnames because I dont know how to make github redirect 404 to index.html